# Detect foreground application and recognize it across restarts

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to be able to have an user select an application (from a list of currently running ones), and then do certain actions in the background when that application is currently the topmost one/focues one.

I am able to get a `hWnd`with `GetForegroundWindow`, but that only works as long as that window is not closed. What is a way to identify from which application a window comes from, even across restarts? Like a Process ID that doesn't change? Or maybe getting the executable name?

Comment: This sounds like plain old desktop automation/tesing. There are existing solutions for this. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Is the application to be detected a UWP app or you want to detect other foreground app from a UWP app?